# VisualBasic web browser not showing images/css

Tags: css, vba

I have no idea how to fix this. i've tried alot of things.
[image]

```
    Dim Browse As New WebBrowser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(1, "Page " & i + 1)
    TabControl1.SelectTab(i)
    Browse.Name = "wb"
    Browse.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Browse.ObjectForScripting = True
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browse)
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hi,**

you want to do a Browse action to a static page which loads a css? Like so? And this page does not load the pictures? Did I understand that right?
If not, please explain it to me a little bit better, what you want.

So if I have this inside the css:

```
.browserTestVB {
  background: url(http://localhost/system-center-2016-tp5.png) no-repeat;
  width: 1000px; 
  height: 562px; 
}
```

And this inside the page

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>IIS 10.1.1</title>
    <link href="http://localhost/index.css" type="text/css" 
      rel="stylesheet" />
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <img src="system-center-2016-tp5-leer.png" alt="IIS 9.0.1"
            width="1000" height="562" class="browserTestVB" />
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

This shows in my little test the page with the loaded css and the picture which is set in css.

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim i = 0

        Dim Browse As New WebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(1, "Page " & i + 1)
        TabControl1.SelectTab(i)
        Browse.Name = "wb"
        Browse.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Browse.ObjectForScripting = True
        Browse.Navigate("http://localhost")
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browse)
        i = i + 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

**OK - I read your amendment.**

That is only a question of the path to the css or from css in your related htlm code. You have to check the paths. First - to avoid path problems - I would try it by URL paths like so

background:url(http://localhost/system-center-2016-tp5.png)

You do the same for the css files like so

```
<link href="http://localhost/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

instead of folder paths. I guess it's only that. After you see that's working, you change it to folder paths.

**OK - I read your amendment**

If you want it from here you point the URL in css or html to my picture for example:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/28jJj.jpg?s=32&amp;g=1" alt="" height="32" width="32">
```

Within VB you only navigate to the start URL like so:

> Browse.Navigate("http://localhost")

Within these pages you can do what you want to do.

**OK - I guess now I got your idea**

First of all - thanks for your votes. I guess you are making something like a site for your reputation? That's a fine idea [image: just fine] .

Axel Arnold Bangert - Herzogenrath 2016

Comment: I have buttons that do everything else, like navigation, etc. however when i goto some webpages it won't load the CSS on them.

Comment: close to what im saying, but how would i load the CSS and images, from a ONLINE web page, for example stack exchange